# Is it possible to create Schema.org offers for lease items?

Tags: schema.org

I am trying to create markup for vehicles that are available for lease.

These vehicles have three offers attached to them:

- Buy now
- Zero down lease
- Lease with down payment

I have looked through the Schema.org properties and can't seem to find any property that lets me define the payment schedule (monthly, weekly etc.) or define a down payment and then incremental payments after.

Comment: Your JSON-LD is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the https://schema.org/BusinessFunction for the Offer

> The business function specifies the type of activity or access (i.e., the bundle of rights) offered by the organization or business person through the offer. Typical are sell, rental or **lease**, maintenance or repair, manufacture / produce, recycle / dispose, engineering / construction, or installation. Proprietary specifications of access rights are also instances of this class. 
>    Commonly used values:
>
> ...
>
> **http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#LeaseOut**
>
> ...

Maybe you can combine them with the https://schema.org/PayAction or https://schema.org/RentAction as a https://schema.org/potentialAction on your Offer